# does asp.net core web applications come under uwp?

Tags: asp.net-core, uwp

I saw in some blogs that apps for windows pc, windows phone etc come under **uwp**. But I cound not find anywhere mentioning if asp.net core web application comes under uwp. If yes then can we apply Microsoft's new **fluent** design to a asp.net core web app?

Comment: UWP is for client UIs.  ASP.Net Core is a server architecture and has nothing to do with any of this.  You can run a server anywhere you want.

Comment: so can I apply fluent design to an asp.net core web application ?

Comment: Microsoft's Fluent Design APIs are part of Windows, not the browser DOM.

Comment: It definitely is somehow possible according to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/MichaelGillett/status/863805417897570305) but I have no idea how and you have to create it on you own - there are no Microsoft's CSS styles or whatever for that in asp.net.

Comment: Microsoft's Fluent Design is just on design style. It can be used every where like UWP app, website even iOS/Android apps.  However, Microsoft only provides APIs for UWP apps now. With these APIs, you can implement Fluent Design easily in your UWP app. But if you want to achieve the same effects in your web application, you have to do this with CSS and JS by yourself.